# Why won't my website load in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html

I just noticed after upgrading to IE9 that my personal website does not load on Internet Expolorer.

My guess is that it has something to do with the Javascript music player, but i'm not certain.

Here is the website:  http://itsnotch.com

here is the souce code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>ItsNotch.com 'The Biography of Big Notch'</title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/itsnotch-apple-icon2.png"/>
<meta name="description" content="Big Notch Biography, Its Notch, ItsNotch, It's Notch, It'sNotch, Big Notch Journal, Big Notch Blog, Big Notch Web Designer, Big Notch tech guru, Tech Guru, New Orleans Tech Guru, Louisiana Tech Guru, LA Tech Guru, New Orleans Tech Geek, New Orleans Geek BigNotch, bignotch, big notch the beat maker, big notch the producer, big notch beats, beats by big notch">

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19744657-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.itsnotch.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(images/itsnotchbg.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -900px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.introDiv {
    position:relative;
    top:-130px;
    left:155px;
    height:460px;
    width:460px;
    background:url(images/introduction.jpg)
}

#menuList {
    position:relative;
    top:-460px;
    left:-310px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
    border:hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0px;
    border:0;
}

.txtStyle1 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width:430px;
    padding-top:35px;
    padding-right:5;

}

#creditDiv {

    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:-100px;
}


#playerDiv {
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:300px;
    margin-top:-90px;
    z-index:2;



}


a:link {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#333; 
}
a:visited {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}
a:hoover {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}
a:active {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#06F;
}
</style>
<body>

<!--The Notch Muisc Player-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/SCMmusic/script.php" ><!--
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
SCMMusicPlayer.init("{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','playback':{'autostart':'true','shuffle':'true','volume':'40'},'playlist':[{'title':'NewYorkish','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Council Music (Instrumental).mp3'},{'title':'Pharcyde - BS','url':'http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/audio/The Pharcyde- Bullshit (Instrumental).mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - Von Sees','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/02 Von Sees.mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - Raw Life','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/03 Raw Life.mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - Nics Groove','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/06 Nic%27s Groove.mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - Be Alright','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/07 Be Alright.mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - Come Around','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/11 Come Around.mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - Happiness','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/12 Happiness.mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - All That You Are','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/14 All That You Are.mp3'},{'title':'Foreign Exchange - Call','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/16 Call.mp3'},{'title':'Little Brother','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/LittleBrother.mp3'},{'title':'Jay Dilla Madlib','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Pyramids .mp3'},{'title':'Jay Dilla - Floating Soul','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Floating Soul.mp3'},{'title':'The Roots - Hypnotic','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Hypnotic.mp3'}],'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':'false'}");
//--></script>
<!--End Notch Player Script-->




<center>
<img src="images/pageslab1.gif">
<!-- header -->
<div id="header"><img src="images/header1.jpg" alt="header" name="header2" width="797" height="497" id="banner"></div>
<!-- Intro Section -->
<div class="introDiv">
<div class="txtStyle1">Welcome to <u>ItsNotch.com</u>. My name is Josh, but my friends have called me "Big Notch" for years. I do web design and development as a hobby.  I'm a Tech Enthusiast. But some people might call me a "Tech Guru". I love to create things. I am also a musician at heart, and have been a long time. You can visit the my music website at <a href="http://www.bignotch.com"/>www.bignotch.com</a>. <br><br>I currently attend college and created this website for a course project at my school, but at the last minute I decided to turn it into a public website. I coded this website from scratch and with no web building tools.<br><br>  This site serves as my official online biography, resume, portfolio, and blog all rolled into one. Take a look through the website and enjoy.

</div>

</div>

<!-- Menu Buttons -->
<div id="menuList">
    <a href="/"><img src="/images/buttons/intro_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>
    <a href="/bio.html"><img src="/images/buttons/bio_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>
    <a href="/experience.html"><img src="/images/buttons/exp_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>
    <a href="/portfolio.html"><img src="/images/buttons/portfolio_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>
    <a href="/travels.html"><img src="/images/buttons/travel_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>
    <a href="/blog"><img src="/images/buttons/blog_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>

    <a href="/ask.html"><img src="/images/buttons/formspring_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>
    <a href="/contact.html"><img src="/images/buttons/contact_btn.png" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"></a>
    </div>



    <!-- Credit -->

    <div id="creditDiv">
    Site Designed and Coded by <b>Big Notch</b>
    </div>

    <!-- Player -->

    <div id="playerDiv">


    </div>

    </center>

<!-- TWEETBOARD CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var _tbdef = {user: 'bignotchonline'}; 
(function(){ 
var d = document;var tbjs = d.createElement('script'); tbjs.type = 'text/javascript'; 
tbjs.async = true; tbjs.src = 'http://tweetboard.com/tb.js'; var tbel = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
if(!tbel) tbel = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; tbel.appendChild(tbjs);
})(); 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's your music player code:

```
SCMMusicPlayer.init("{ // <<< Remove this double quote
    'skin':'skins/black/skin.css',
    'playback': {
        'autostart':'true',
        'shuffle':'true',
        'volume':'40'
    },
    'playlist': [
        {
            'title':'NewYorkish',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Council Music (Instrumental).mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Pharcyde - BS',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/audio/The Pharcyde- Bullshit (Instrumental).mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - Von Sees',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/02 Von Sees.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - Raw Life',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/03 Raw Life.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - Nics Groove',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/06 Nic%27s Groove.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - Be Alright',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/07 Be Alright.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - Come Around',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/11 Come Around.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - Happiness',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/12 Happiness.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - All That You Are',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/14 All That You Are.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Foreign Exchange - Call',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/16 Call.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Little Brother',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/LittleBrother.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Jay Dilla Madlib',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Pyramids .mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'Jay Dilla - Floating Soul',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Floating Soul.mp3'
        },
        {
            'title':'The Roots - Hypnotic',
            'url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/Hypnotic.mp3'
        }
    ],
    'placement':'bottom',
    'showplaylist':'false'
}"); // <<< Remove this double quote
```

**EDIT**

It's definitely the music player; simply adding this line makes IE9 get confused what it needs to do:

```
SCMMusicPlayer.init("{}");
```

**EDIT2**

You need to check your configuration of the music player. I didn't get it to completely work (music plays, but rest of the page does load correctly), but this will help you get closer to where you need to be.

In your script.php file, the form action is not correct (hence the 404 not found):

```
scmCode+='<form action="'+this.url+'" method="post" id="scmSendData" target="scmFrame"><input name="scmData" id="scmData" type="hidden" value="'+this.dataStr+'" /></form>';
```

When I changed this from what it was ("../download something or other"), the video player started loading at the bottom of the screen. You'll notice two lines below this piece of code, there is:

```
document.getElementById('scmSendData').submit();
```

Which is submitting the form to a url that is not correct. It should just be `this.url`, which is set towards the top of the script.php file (at the beginning of the `init()` method).

Comment: I don't know yet - I had to format it so I could corner the issue.

Comment: @Edward Thomas - See my two comments in the code. You need to remove the double quotes at the beginning and end of the .init() function call.

Comment: I see on their website that they generate the code with the double quoted string. I don't understand why they are doing this.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the double-quoted string; it has to do with what the SCCMusicPlayer is doing when you call init() and pass in the string. If you remove the double quotes, it just doesn't run the music player. That's why it appears to work. Except, the music never plays.

Answer (score 0):

I see : 404 Error File Not Found
The page you are looking for might have been removed, 
had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Maybe its something you should work out with web host